# Why is HashMap not in normal form upon series of inserts?

Tags: haskell, strictness, unordered-containers

I've been trying to ensure the strictness of an in-memory model of a Haskell program using ghc-heap-view package and the utils it provides when I noticed that my `HashMap`s don't seem to be in NF upon a series on inserts. I tried printing Heap tree and indeed it shows some thunks. I then tried another way of inserting elements (using `union` and `singleton`) and this time it comes out strict.

Could somebody please explain why is this so and advise if there's anything I can do to make `insert` behave the same way as the other method?

Here's my test code:

```
module Main where

import           Control.Exception           (evaluate)
import           Data.Foldable
import           Data.HashMap.Strict         (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict         as HM
import           GHC.HeapView

test1 :: HashMap Int Int
test1 = foldl' (\m v -> HM.insert v v m) HM.empty [0..5]

test2 :: HashMap Int Int
test2 = foldl' (\m v -> HM.union (HM.singleton v v) m) HM.empty [0..5]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "HeapTree for test1"
  t1 <- evaluate test1
  buildHeapTree 10 (asBox t1) >>= print . ppHeapTree

  putStrLn "HeapTree for test2"
  t2 <- evaluate test2
  buildHeapTree 10 (asBox t2) >>= print . ppHeapTree
```

And here's the output:

```
HeapTree for test1
"BitmapIndexed ([ (_thunk (I# 0) (I# 0) 0), (_thunk (I# 1) (I# 1) 1), (Leaf (I# 2) (I# 2) 2), (Leaf (I# 3) (I# 3) 3), (Leaf (I# 4) (I# 4) 4), (Leaf (I# 5) (I# 5) 5) ]) 63"
HeapTree for test2
"BitmapIndexed ([ (Leaf (I# 0) (I# 0) 0), (Leaf (I# 1) (I# 1) 1), (Leaf (I# 2) (I# 2) 2), (Leaf (I# 3) (I# 3) 3), (Leaf (I# 4) (I# 4) 4), (Leaf (I# 5) (I# 5) 5) ]) 63"
(0.02 secs, 1,067,672 bytes)
```

Comment: Those thunks seem to be for internal nodes of the map. Looking at the documentation for the strictness properties (version 0.2.9.0 http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.9.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#g:1) it only says that *keys* and *values* are reduced to WHNF, but says nothing about the internal nodes.

Comment: If there are really thunks anywhere in a `HashMap` constructed using only strict operations, I'd call that a bug; for performance, we don't want that. What version of `unordered-containers` are you using? Please open a ticket.

Comment: I've tested this with tip of `unorder-containers` master branch (0.2.10.0). I have created a simple project to demonstrate this behaviour: https://github.com/mantasg/hashmap-test. I also created a ticket: https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers/issues/232.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the helper function `two` in `Data.HashMap.Base`, which isn't strict in its key arguments. But I'm still surprised, because I'd expect inlining to reveal that those arguments have been forced.

Comment: Ah.... I guess probably because `two` is defined as a (recursive) `go` function....

Comment: You seem to be right. Adding bangs to the arguments of `go` inside `two` fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inserting a new, non-colliding key into a `Leaf` node, `insert` uses a helper function called `two` to generate a two-element map. The `two` function is lazy in the values of the keys, which leads to GHC creating thunks to create the two new `Leaf` nodes. This whole thing is pretty silly, because the keys are actually certain to be in WHNF by then. But (presumably because of a recursive `go` function) GHC doesn't realize that. The problem should be fixed in the next version of `unordered-containers`.